# How to identify an existing table in word document using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, import, ms-word

Can someone help me to identify the existing table in the word document which already imported to excel using VBA.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Provide some code as a starting point. How should the table be identified? Is it the only one in the document? The last one? Should it be worked with immediately after being imported from Excel? Use the [edit] link below the question to provide more information. And please take a moment to read the site guidelines about asking question on Stack Overflow in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

Word has a Tables collection which can be stepped through. Within a table there is a Cell collection to identify cells. So in Word you can write

```
Sub test()
Dim t As Table
     For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables

          If Left(t.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, 8) = "This One" Then
              MsgBox "Found It!"
              t.Select
          End If
     Next t
End Sub
```

to search each table for the text "This One" in the top left hand corner. Does this help?